# C# lists and datagridviews

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate a datagrid with info out of a list, and then after pressing a save button it saves the datagrid changes back into the list.

```
    int pos = MainMenu.myList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == validID);
    var tempStu = MainMenu.myList[pos];
    if (tempStu is DormStudent)
    {
        DormStudent tempDorm = tempStu as DormStudent;
        nameTextBox.Text = tempDorm.Name;
        var blist = new BindingList<Student>(tempDorm.Grades);
        var source = new BindingSource(blist, null);
        gradesDataGridView.DataSource = source;
    }
    else
    {
        nameTextBox.Text = tempStu.Name;
        var blist = new BindingList<Student>(tempStu.Grades);
        var source = new BindingSource(blist, null);
        gradesDataGridView.DataSource = source;
    }
```

and when you push the save button (i don't have the save part as nice)

```
    int pos = MainMenu.myList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == validID);
    var tempStu = MainMenu.myList[pos];
    if (tempStu is DormStudent)
    {
        DormStudent tempDorm = tempStu as DormStudent;
        tempDorm.Grades = gradesDataGridView;
        MainMenu.myList[pos] = tempDorm;
    }
    else
    {
        tempStu.Grades = gradesDataGridView;
        MainMenu.myList[pos] = tempStu;
    }
```

here's the Student class that the grades is in.

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> Grades;
        public Student()
        {
            ID = 0;
            Name = "No Student";
            Grades = new List<int>();
        }
        public Student(int i, string n)
        {
            ID = i;
            Name = n;
            Grades = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

I can't get either the converting the list to the datagrid when the check button is pressed or back when the save button is pressed. can anyone help with that?

Comment: you didn't ask a question

Comment: i did edit it to have a question very shortly after you posted this.

Comment: I believe this requires the use of viewstates.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see mainly one issue. Note, however, that I am far from being an expert in Data Binding!

I see that you are creating a `BindingList<>` for type `Student`. I hope you actually want to display one Student's grades top down.

If instead you really wanted to display all Students top down and their grades in the columns from left to right you would have to do some serious twisting!

Now the `BindingList` should bind the `Grades` not a `Student`, so the first idea would be to change it to `BindingList<int>`.

However afaik unnamed variables make bad `DataMembers`. To display them the data should be `Properties`.

So I created a new class `Grade` that wraps the integer. For good measure I also added a string Test to hold a description of the the test. Leave it out if you don't want it!

```
public class Grade
{
    public int Points  { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public Grade()
    { Points = 0; Test = "No Test"; }

    public Grade(int points, string test)
    { Points = points; Test = test; }
}
```

This calls for changes in the Student class:

```
public List<Grade> Grades;
```

and (twice)

```
Grades = new List<Grade>();
```

The two lines creating the BindingList now look like this:

```
var blist = new BindingList<Grade>(tempDorm.Grades);
var blist = new BindingList<Grade>(tempStu.Grades);
```

The good news is that not only the data now load fine into the `DataGridView`; there is also **no need at all for the save action**, as the Data are bound **two-way** and every change actually happens in the List!

Only in the event of needing an undo function will you need some more coding, but that is another matter..